# Rails 3: alias_method_chain still used?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was just reading about Gems/Plugin development for Rails 3 and ran across [this post](http://piotrsarnacki.com/2010/06/18/rails-internals-railties/) that says that alias_method_chain is no longer used. I can see the method is still there in activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb.

Should I still be using alias_method_chain in Rails 3?

Is [this](http://6brand.com/counting-with-scope_out-fun-with-alias_method_chain.html) still reflective of the best practices for gems/plugins in Rails 3 that want to modify ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

No, it has been replaced by a clever use of method overriding in modules and the `super` keyword.

Basically, you define the original function in an included module, and override it in another included module. When you call `super` in the overriding function, it calls the original function. But there is one catch. You have to include the extending modules **after** including the base module, and in the order you want the chaining to occur.

```
class Something
  module Base  
    def my_method
      # (A) original functionality
    end
  end

  module PreExtension
    def my_method
      # (B) before the original
      super # calls whatever was my_method before this definition was made
    end
  end

  module PostExtension
    def my_method
      super # calls whatever was my_method before this definition was made
      # (C) after the original
    end
  end

  include Base # this is needed to place the base methods in the inheritance stack
  include PreExtension # this will override the original my_method
  include PostExtension # this will override my_method defined in PreExtension
end

s = Something.new
s.my_method 
#=> this is a twice extended method call that will execute code in this order:
#=> (B) before the original
#=> (A) the original
#=> (C) after the original
```

Ryan Bates of [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com) talks about [how this is used in the Rails Routing code](http://railscasts.com/episodes/232-routing-walkthrough-part-2). I'd recommend watching it, and his other screencasts. They have the power to transform a knitting grandmother into a Rails guru.

*PS: Credit goes to [Peeja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4937/peeja) for correcting a fundamental error in my original answer. Thanks.*

Comment: Sweet! Thanks. I have watched most of the Railscasts I just hadn't seen that one yet.

Comment: I don't believe that's correct.  By my understanding and this experiment, the modules' methods are never called: https://gist.github.com/664352

Answer (score 19):

In general, a module can never override a method in the class
it's included in.  This is because module inclusion works just
like subclassing.  A superclass can't override its subclasses'
methods either, nor would you expect it to.

When a module is included in a class, the module is inserted
just after the class in the class's ancestor chain.  Calling
`super` from the *class* will call the *module*'s implementation.

```
class Something
  module PreExtension; end
  module PostExtension; end

  include PreExtension
  include PostExtension
end

Something.ancestors # => [Something, Something::PostExtension, Something::PreExtension, Object, Kernel]
```

Whenever a method is called on a `Something`, Ruby looks through
this list in order and calls the first implementation it finds.
If the implementation calls `super`, it keeps looking and finds
the next one.

This means that modules included later take precedence over
modules included earlier, and can call `super` to get the earlier
modules' implementations.  This is because included modules are
inserted in the ancestor chain *directly after* the class.  This
is how the routing code edgerunner mentioned works.  That code
puts everything in modules, like so:

```
class SomethingNew
  module Base
    def my_method
      puts "(A)"
    end
  end

  module Extension
    def my_method
      puts "(B)"
      super
    end
  end

  include Base
  include Extension
end

SomethingNew.new.my_method
# Output:
# >> (B)
# >> (A)

SomethingNew.ancestors # => [SomethingNew, SomethingNew::Extension, SomethingNew::Base, Object, Kernel]
```

This is why `alias_method_chain` existed in the first place.  If putting the base code in a module is not an option, I'm not sure how to accomplish the equivalent of `alias_method_chain`.

Comment: this is a great answer, just wish you had an answer to your last question

Comment: Actually, I believe there's no other way to do it.  That's why Rails 3 uses the `module Base` pattern.  That was one of wycats's big pushes in Rails 3.  And if you think about it, it doesn't really make sense that an included module (or a superclass) should be able to change a base class's implementations against its will.

Comment: Well, sometimes you want to extend code that you can't touch. Without `alias_method_chain` I don't see a solution to it.

Comment: There isn't.  But that's considered hacking.  Useful in a pinch, fun to play with, but not something you should depend on for a serious library (and hence not something that Rails uses anymore).  If you'd still like the convenience of `alias_method_chain`, check out the `facets` gem, which still provides it: http://rubyworks.github.com/facets/doc/api/core/Module.html

Answer (score 0):

I see that `alias_method_chain` is no longer present in Rails 3.0.0. http://api.rubyonrails.org/ doesn't report it and `rails console` reports it to be `undefined local variable or method`.

See Also - https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/285-alias_method_chain-limits-extensibility#ticket-285-20

**UPDATE:** As noted by @ecoologic in comments, `alias_method_chain` is still present in Rails 3.1.1.

Comment: [so what is this?](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.1.1.rc1/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb)

Comment: you're welcome, my prev. comment sounds a little rude, sorry that was not my intention