# Gem, custom save method for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I cannot figure this out from what I have read on Google, but I want to make a gem that will alter the behavior of the module when it saves, but I don't know how to do this.  How would I define in the Gem a save method that overrides the model's save method?

**Update:** I have found [Rails 3: alias_method_chain still used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689736/rails-3-alias-method-chain-still-used), which I will check into.  It appears that alias_method_chain is deprecated for Rails 3.

Comment: alter the behaviour how?  like gsub one of the attributes or something to that effect?

Comment: For example, check for true...if false abort save if not continue

Comment: your example can be accomplished with validations. You also have the 'before_save' callback hook, if your behavior is simple. Are you thinking of doing something crazier than that?

Comment: @YenTheFirst I was thinking about doing something crazier.  The reason I asked is because I want to modify a Gems behavior on everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd rather do this :

```
module YourModule

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(InstanceMethods)
  end

  module InstanceMethods

    def save
      # Your behavior here
      super # Use this if you want to call the old save method
    end
  end
end
```

And then in the model :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include YourModule
end
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Using alias_method_chain:

```
module YourModule

  def self.included( base )
    base.send(:include, YourModule::InstanceMethods )
    base.alias_method_chain :save, :action
  end

  module InstanceMethods

    def save_with_action
      # do something here
      save_without_action
    end

  end

end
```

Then you include the module in your AR object:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    include YourModule
end
```

Comment: I am not sure but I think alias_method_chain was deprecated with Rails 3. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689736/rails-3-alias-method-chain-still-used

Comment: even if alias_method_chain itself is deprecated, you can still do the same behavior. instead of 'base.alias_method_chain', you'd just have two 'base.alias_method' calls.