# Override titleize method in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to override the `.titleize` method in RoR?

For example, `titleize` does not work for names like TJ Watson. It converts 'tj watson' to Tj Watson. I would like to add such rules to it.

Also, I don't want to define a new method because my code already uses `.titleize` through it. How can I add features to `titleize` without having to change the method calls throughout the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put some *.rb file in your `initializers` folder with the following content:

```
# encoding: utf-8

module ActiveSupport
  module Inflector
    def titleize(word)
      # old code for referencing:
      # humanize(underscore(word)).gsub(/\b(?<!['’`])[a-z]/) { $&.capitalize }
      < your code goes here >
    end
  end
end
```

Also check this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10471857/1322562.

Comment: Question: When i do this code, I get the following:  /config/initializers/inflections.rb:16: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ')'
...erscore(word)).gsub(/\b(?<!['’`])[a-z]/) { $&.capitalize } ------- I'm assuming that this is due to encoding? How do i fix this?

Comment: Did you put the `# encoding: utf-8` line at the very beginning of your file? It's a magic comment. It has to be there.

Comment: Great. I had to remove one of the apostrophe like characters for it to work.  Question: if I wanted to leave dashes ( - ) in the string, how would I do that? For example, currently "james franklin-howard".titleize => "James Franklin Howard" ... how would I get James Franklin-Howard ?