# How to monkey-patch an ActionView module via prepend?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, monkeypatching, prepend

If you include a module `Foo` in a class `SomeClass`, then prepend that module with another module `Bar`, any method-overwriting inside `Bar` will not take effect in `SomeClass`. Example:

```
module Foo
  def some_method
    puts 'In Foo'
  end
end

class SomeClass
  include Foo
end

SomeClass.new.some_method # => 'In Foo'

module Bar
  def some_method
    puts 'In Bar'
    super
  end
end

Foo.prepend Bar

Foo.ancestors # => [Bar, Foo]

SomeClass.new.some_method # => 'In Foo'

class AnotherClass
  include Foo
end

AnotherClass.new.some_method # => 
# 'In Bar'
# 'In Foo'
```

I am trying to monkey-patch an ActionView helper method the following way:

In `lib/core_extensions/action_view/helpers/url_helper/secure_link_to`:

```
module CoreExtensions
  module ActionView
    module Helpers
      module UrlHelper
        module SecureLinkTo
          def link_to(name = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil, &block)
            html_options ||= {}
            if html_options[:target].present?
              html_options[:rel] = 'noopener noreferrer'
            end

            super(name, options, html_options, &block)
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and then in an initializer:

```
ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper.prepend CoreExtensions::ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper::SecureLinkTo
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. My assumption - by the time the initializer executes, `ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper` has already been included (in wherever it is supposed to be included) and thus the prepending doesn't seem to take effect. Does anybody know a solution to this?

Comment: why not just reopen `ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper` and define the method there? (apart from that your approach feels somewhat more cleaner)

Comment: Well, exactly as you say - I would like to do it in a clean way. I am following this: http://nofail.de/2014/06/monkey-patching-rails/ and this article recommends `prepend` as the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without answering your specific question about module prepend, here would be another way:

Since helpers in Rails are global, you can simply create your own helper with the `link_to` method overridden.

```
module LinkHelper
  def link_to(name = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil, &block)
    html_options ||= {}
    if html_options[:target].present?
      html_options[:rel] = 'noopener noreferrer'
    end

    super(name, options, html_options, &block)
  end
end
```

Somehow this seems less `hacky` than creating an initializer, because I don't need to hardcode the inheritence chain in the helper module.

Comment: Thank you for your anser, Magnuss. Where do I put this file?

Comment: @AlexPopov It's a plain old helper module. You put it in `app/helpers`.

Comment: For reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471535/override-rails-helpers-with-access-to-original