# overwriting a module method and referencing it as well

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a module included in one of my models. being specific in my user model database_authenticatable is included.

```
devise  :database_authenticatable
```

The module has a method valid_password?(password) I want to overwrite the method as follow

```
def valid_password?(password)
  if my_condition_is_true
    do_something_new()
  else
    # do  what valid_password(password) always does
  end
end
```

in my else I'm thinking of copying whatever is defined insdide of valid_password() in database_authenticatable.rb module, but i'm wondering if there is a way to just tell it to do that? like in inheritance I can do super?

Also I realized no mether what, after calling my valid_password method, it cals the module valid_password method, any idea how to avoid this?

Comment: See this answer for a couple of ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4471202/2988

Answer (score 1):

You could write your modification as a module and include it so it's loaded similarly to how the module with the previous method was loaded. If you can do this you should be able to call `super` correctly.

Have a look at this thread for some ideas (it'll depend on how the rest of your code looks, of course): [Rails 3: alias_method_chain still used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689736/rails-3-alias-method-chain-still-used)