# To extend rails' `link_to`, should I use `alias_method_chain` or mixins + inheritance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

I'm creating an app using [twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/). I'm using [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/) to add icons to various places, very often links. So far I've been using a global helper. Here's the simplified version:

```
# app/helpers/link_to_with_icon.rb
def link_to_with_icon(text, path, options={})
  options = options.clone
  icon = options.delete(:icon)
  text = "<i class='#{icon}'></i> #{text}" if icon.present?
  link_to(text, path, options)
end
```

This worked, but I had to remember changing `link_to` to `link_to_with_icon` every time I needed to add an icon to a new link (the app is new, so that's kindof in constant flux). So I decided to stop using `link_to` completely, and replaced it with `link_to_with_icon` (since it is compatible).

But then I realized that since I'm not using `link_to` any more, I might as well modify `link_to` in the first place. Surely I could add some monkeypatching on the lib folder to make it understand the `:icon` option.

```
# lib/extensions/url_helper_extensions.rb
module ActionView
  module Helpers
    module UrlHelper

      # do some magic here

    end
  end
end
```

I've done things similar to this before, a couple years ago. In that time `alias_method_chain` helper was the right tool for the job. In rails 3.x it seems to be [deprecated in favor of modules and inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689736/rails-3-alias-method-chain-still-used).

But if I'm understanding the examples in that page correctly, I would need the `link_to` method to be provided by some kind of `Base` module - otherwise you can't add a "Pre-Extension" to it.

Hence my question: **Can I extend link_to using modules? Or must I use `alias_method_chain`?**

In particular, a working implementation of the `:icon` option would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd simply do:

```
# app/helpers/my_helper.rb

module MyHelper
  def link_to(text, path, options={})
    options = options.clone
    icon = options.delete(:icon)
    text = "<i class='#{icon}'></i> #{text}" if icon.present?
    super(text, path, options)
  end
end
```

But watch out if ever you use `link_to` with block.

Comment: Why not send the block through too? Also, did you mean to call the method `link_to`?

Comment: @apneadiving I'm assuming you will also want to include the module in ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper, right?

Comment: @kikito no need, give it a try

Comment: Oh, you are also using a helper in app/helpers, not a file inside lib. Gotcha.

Comment: That's right, I use only helpers in this kind of cases, otherwise I rely on presenters

Comment: Ok, I edited your answer a bit and accepted it. Feel free to revert the changes if you don't agree. Regards!

Answer (score 3):

I would either add this in a separate helper, or add it into `ApplicationHelper`

```
def link_to(text, path, options = {}, &block)
  icon = options.delete(:icon)
  text = content_tag(:i, text, :class => icon) if icon
  super
end
```

And you don't want to clone the options Hash because you don't want the `icon` option to be sent to the original `link_to` method.

Comment: Good point about just using a helper. Thanks. Regarding cloning: Take a closer look. The `:icon` option is not being sent to `link_to`. But I don't want to modify `options` directly since it might be used in several links (delete is a destructive method, it modifies the hash).

Comment: Ah alright that makes sense. Then just the same code as above but with your original cloning should do the trick.