# Ruby - Is there a way to call a method of the superclass with the same name of a method overloaded

Tags: ruby, oop

Is it possible to do something like:

```
class A
  def a(var)
    puts "do something with #{var}"
  end
end

class B < A
  def a(var)
    var = var + "some modification"
    #this is what I want to do:
    super.a(var)
  end
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: In your example is B class not a subclass of A and object doesn'T have a methode a, so what do you whant to do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689736/rails-3-alias-method-chain-still-used may be related

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I'm misreading your question, you should be able to call `super` by itself; e.g.:

```
class A
  def a(var)
    puts "do something with #{var}"
  end
end

class B < A
  def a(var)
    var = var + "some modification"
    #this is what I want to do:
    #super.a(var)
    super
  end
end

v = B.new
v.a("hey")
```

produces

```
$ ruby test.rb
do something with heysome modification
```

Comment: If you call `super` like this, it'll pass its arguments along to the parent function (usually what you want).  You can also call `super()` (empty arg list) to invoke the parent function with no args, or `super("whatever")` to explicitly call the parent method with whatever args you want.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a method name with the `super` call

If you use `super` on it's own then it will call the `super` class' implementation passing along the same arguments

```
class A
  def a(var)
    puts var
  end
end

class B < A
  def a(var)
    super
  end
end

B.new.a(1) #=> 1
```

If you want to modify the variable then you can either reassign the `var` arg or use a `super` call passing in arguments

```
class A
  def a(var)
    puts var
  end
end

class B < A
  def a(var)
    var = 2
    super
  end
end

B.new.a(1) #=> 2
```

or

```
class A
  def a(var)
    puts var
  end
end

class B < A
  def a(var)
    super(2)
  end
end

B.new.a(1) #=> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

*try the below:*

```
class A
  def a(var)
    puts "do something with #{var}"
  end
end

class B < A
  def a(var)
    var = var + "some modification"
    #this is what I want to do:
    #super.a(var)
    self.class.superclass.instance_method(:a).bind(self).call 12
  end
end

v = B.new
v.a("hello")
```

***Output:***

```
do something with 12
```

Another one:

```
class A
  def a(var)
    puts "do something with #{var}"
  end
end

class B < A
    alias :old_a :a
  def a(var)
    var = var + "some modification"
    #this is what I want to do:
    #super.a(var)
    old_a 12
  end
end

v = B.new
v.a("hello")
```

***Output:***

```
do something with 12
```

Comment: I think this is solving a problem in an overly complicated way - see the other answers

Comment: @Paul.s `alias` is complicated way? Bummer I just shown OP how many ways we can do it.

Comment: But why go through the extra effort and complexity when it's built into the language? If the OP doesn't know the core language that well then meta programming is completely out of reach.

Comment: **Down-voter:** why down vote? put reasons what wrong in my code. If you don't understand then it doesn't mean code is wrong.You are not capable. So read more more before judge other's codes.

Comment: @Paul.s does `alias` is not ruby's one or `bind` is not. What do you mean?

Comment: I mean the `super` keyword is built in for this purpose. So reimplementing what it does is just unhelpful and unclear